# Target type casting for method arguments , Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Consider the following two functional interfaces ( `java.lang.Runnable and java.util.concurrent.Callable<V>`):

```
public interface Runnable {
    void run();
}

public interface Callable<V> {
    V call();
}
```

Suppose that you have `overloaded` the method invoke as follows:

```
void invoke(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
}

<T> T invoke(Callable<T> c) {
    return c.call();
}
```

Consider below method invokation

```
String s = invoke(() -> "done");
```

This will call `invoke(Callable)` . but How? How compliler is able to determine the Type as callable? I didn't understand from Oracle doc i have read.

Comment: Does this actually compile?

Comment: @christopher Yes it will .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `() -> "done"` returns a string value *"done"* which is what the `call` method of a `Callable` is responsible for in:

```
String s = invoke(() -> "done"); 
// from impl. of 'invoke', the variable 's' is assigned value "done"
```

On the other hand `run` is a `void` method, what matches the type `Runnable` there could be a void call such as:

```
invoke(() -> System.out.println("done"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `() -> "done"` is a lambda that returns a value and has no input parameters. Since `Runnable` neither returns a value nor has input parameters, `() -> "done"` can't match the signature of your overload `invoke(Runnable)`.

If you were to add a signature with `Supplier` (or any other functional interface that takes no parameters but returns a value), it wouldn't be able to determine whether you want to call the `Callable` or the `Supplier` version.